# Facing build issue after updating the flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, build

I am this error while building for device for iOS in flutter repeatedly, I have tried many things but no resolution yet. This issue is occurring with flutter firebase project and the release is stuck for more than 4 days. I need updated guide for me to resolve this issue as soon as possible

I have updated the flutter and current versions are Flutter 1.20.3 and dart  2.9.2

> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file
> reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h"
> is a member
> of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved
> (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a
> member of multiple
> groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but
> membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h"
> is a member of
> multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but
> membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a
> member of multiple
> groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but
> membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
> reference to the same path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member
> of multiple groups
> ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
> targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of
> multiple groups
> ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
> targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member
> of multiple groups
> ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the
> groups will be preserved (but membership in
> targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
> path.
> 2020-09-05 12:53:42.052 xcodebuild[72084:478348] warning:  The file reference for
> "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h"
> is a
> member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
> membership in one of the groups will be
> preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add
> another reference to the same path.
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> In file included from /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param sharedStyle
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
> in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> tapToDismissEnabled
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param queueEnabled
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> 4 warnings generated.
> In file included from /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param sharedStyle
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
> in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> tapToDismissEnabled
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param queueEnabled
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> 4 warnings generated.
> In file included from /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param sharedStyle
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
> in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> tapToDismissEnabled
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param queueEnabled
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:20:23:
> warning: unused variable 'viewController'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> UIViewController *viewController =
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:99:21:
> warning: unused variable 'topPadding'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:100:21:
> warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:73:19:
> warning: unused variable 'size'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
> ^
> 8 warnings generated.
> In file included from /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param sharedStyle
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found
> in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9:
> note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
> @param allowTapToDismiss
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> tapToDismissEnabled
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20:
> warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param'
> command [-Wdocumentation]
> @param queueEnabled
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:20:23:
> warning: unused variable 'viewController'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> UIViewController *viewController =
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:99:21:
> warning: unused variable 'topPadding'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:100:21:
> warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.0.4/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:73:19:
> warning: unused variable 'size'
> [-Wunused-variable]
> NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
> ^
> 8 warnings generated.
> 6 warnings generated.
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43:
> warning:
> 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling.
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage
> *)remoteMessage {
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1:
> note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly
> marked deprecated here
> __deprecated_msg(
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
> In module 'Foundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
> In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
> :6:
> In module 'Darwin' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
> dation.h:16:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48:
> note: expanded from macro
> '__deprecated_msg'
> #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) **attribute**((**deprecated**(_msg)))
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:24:
> warning:
> 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling.
> [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1:
> note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly
> marked deprecated here
> __deprecated_msg(
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
> In module 'Foundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
> In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
> :6:
> In module 'Darwin' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
> dation.h:16:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48:
> note: expanded from macro
> '__deprecated_msg'
> #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) **attribute**((**deprecated**(_msg)))
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30:
> warning:
> 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message
> delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:283:56:
> note: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' has been
> explicitly marked deprecated here
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldEstablishDirectChannel DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
> In module 'Foundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
> In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
> :6:
> In module 'Darwin' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
> dation.h:16:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:182:64:
> note: expanded from macro
> 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
> #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) **attribute**((deprecated(s)))
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52:
> warning: 'appData' is
> deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62:
> note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated
> here
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
> In module 'Foundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
> In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
> :6:
> In module 'Darwin' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
> dation.h:16:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60:
> note: expanded from macro
> 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
> #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        **attribute**((deprecated))
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:306:1:
> warning: implementing
> deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
> - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:253:1:
> note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared
> here
> - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
> ^
> /Users/vickky/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63:
> warning: 'appData' is
> deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
> [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
> ^
> In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62:
> note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated
> here
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
> ^
> In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
> In module 'Foundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
> In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h
> :6:
> In module 'Darwin' imported from
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoun
> dation.h:16:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.5.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:180:60:
> note: expanded from macro
> 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
> #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        **attribute**((deprecated))
> ^
> 6 warnings generated.
> 1 warning generated.
> Failed to subset font; aborting.
>
> ```
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h
> ```
>
> (in target 'TOCropViewController'
> from project 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
> 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from
> project 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
> 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
> 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
> 'Pods')
> warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
> /Users/vickky/Documents/project1/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h
> (in target
> 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: can you try downgrading to flutter `1.17.5`?

Comment: @MJMontes Sure I can try this ,but I am not getting specific procedure for this after googling. please suggest me the procedure for the same. thanks

Comment: to downgrade to the version I mentioned, run `flutter version v1.17.5`
you can also try the answer below.

Comment: @MJMontes thank you for guiding, I tried below steps already but to no good as of now. hopefully downgrade works

Comment: even downgrade didnt worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the image cropper see here: [not able to build project in iOS](https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/issues/152)

The way I solved it was:

- I deleted the `Pods` folder & `Podfile` & `Podfile.lock` under the iOS folder
- I ran `flutter clean` & `flutter packages get`

If it doesn't work, try the stable channel `flutter channel stable`, and then go back to `flutter channel master` and repeat the steps above in each step. Sometimes switching channels fixes things for some reason.